# Error on file uploading... AccessDenied: Access Denied

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I trying to upload file form frontend to s3 bucket manage all credential from frontend but I showing error access denied in react js
can anyone give me solution of it ?

Comment: Please provide some minimum runnable code so the community can help with debugging.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.